# Customize confirmation page after submitting google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

I have this google [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1kHAz8hX9ustZofRH8TpXHuiBExG-IjCfNI-BZDs08XI/viewform) (**just using google drive**), this is like a test with multiple choices, so the thing is when a user completes the form and clicks on submit button, I want the confirmation page shows the test results.

Is it possible?

I try using creating scripts and using events and triggers, but I'm start to thinking I've misunderstand its usefulness.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a form with Google Apps Script and show the results at the end. Events and triggers may not be the right way to go, but you can try your hand at [UiService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service) with which you can create your forms.

Comment: Should I create the form via code too?, I've just use Google Drive can you provide any example?

Comment: Yes, you have to create the form via code.As I said, you can use UiService or HTMLService for this purpose. I don't think you can customize the confirmation page too much using Google Drive forms only. As another alternative, you can send an email to the submitter with the results